# cut command inside if statement fails

Tags: bash, scripts

Inside a bash script, I have an if-statement. That statement evaluates if a specific part of a string (contained in a variable) is equal to another string. I use a `cut` command to isolate the string part that I want to compare. I have tried  few different options but this is the one I feel ought to work. but it doesn't:

Lets say that `$VAR1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN.csv"`

```
if [ "$VAR1"| cut -c 7-18 = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]; then
..do stuff..
```

Just to be sure I have tested the output of `"$VAR1"| cut -c 7-18` and it results in the exact same string I am comparing it to.

Has anyone got an idea why this won't work?

Comment: I'm skeptical that `"$VAR1"| cut -c 7-18` works as you describe - did you mean `echo "$VAR1"| cut -c 7-18` perhaps?

Comment: Wow all you guys are amazing. And all 3 solution look to be correct. I can only choose one as the accepted answer. I have to go with the answer from @JoL because he explained best what my syntax error actualy was, as well as offer a solution using cut and using the alternative substring which I didnt even know about. I will be upvoting all 3 answers. Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [ "$VAR1"| cut -c 7-18 = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]; then
```

What this does is execute `[ "$VAR1"` and pipe the output to `cut -c 7-18 = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]`. `[` will fail because it requires its last argument to be `]`, and `cut` will fail because probably neither `=` nor `]` are files.

I'm going to guess what you wanted was:

```
if [ "$(echo "$VAR1" | cut -c 7-18)" = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]; then
```

Notice how I wrap the command in `"$()"`. That causes it to execute and substitute its place with the output. Quotes are important, so the output is not split into multiple arguments for `[`.

Following what I believe to be best practices for bash, I would recommend doing this, instead:

```
if [[ "$(cut -c 7-18 <<< "$VAR1")" = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]]; then
```

This avoids special interpretation of `$VAR1` by echo (depending on content, it might mistake it for options), and calling 2 needless executables, `[` and `echo`. Something special to note here is that you don't really need any of the quotes I used. `[[` is a special syntax of bash, and even if the substitution had spaces, bash would not word-split it. It would also not split what was given to `<<<`.  `GHIJKLMN.csv` does not have any whitespace or special characters, so it would also be fine. When in doubt though, it's a good habit to quote everything.

You could've also skipped the call to `cut` by doing this:

```
if [[ "${VAR1:6:12}" = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]]; then
```

Now, everything is done in bash without executing any other program. In this syntax, instead of giving the range of characters you want like you did to `cut`, you provide the 0-based offset to the first character and the number of characters you want. That's 7 - 1 because `cut`'s indices start with 1, and 12 because the range 7-18 is inclusive, so 18 - 7 + 1.

I just saw, your `$VAR1` is `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMN.csv"`. Since you cut to the end, you don't really need to specify the count:

```
if [[ "${VAR1:6}" = "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Beginning of script'
VAR1='ABCDEFGHIJKLMN.csv'
if [ $(echo "$VAR1" | cut -c 7-18) == "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]; then
    echo 'If condition triggered.'
fi
echo 'End of script'
```

This also works:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Beginning of script'
VAR1='ABCDEFGHIJKLMN.csv'
VAR2=$(echo "$VAR1" | cut -c 7-18)
if [ "$VAR2" == "GHIJKLMN.csv" ]; then
    echo 'If condition triggered.'
fi
echo 'End of script'
```